# RS232 java Linux

Tags: java, linux, serial-port

I'm searching a program which could receive and emit caracters with a rs232 connection. I have a program, on the link down there, but for Linux : [How to call a string to appear in another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716011/how-to-call-a-string-to-appear-in-another-class/15716180)
This program can receive caracters from an other PC, but it can't emit caracters. I tried to put, in the public static void main, the function to send caracters but it doesn't work.
Have you got some solutions ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code you find only has a RX handler which reads data from the serial port. You have to add a TX handler in order to emit the data. Check [this link](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Two_way_communcation_with_the_serial_port) as an example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try this code on Wednesday.